# Get Text From URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, callback

How can i call in php words from url?

Example 1

```
http://myurl.com/keyword-one
```

I want to display "Keyword One" as page title in php

Example 2

```
http://myurl.com/keyword/keyword-two
```

I want to display "Keyword Two" as page title in php

Thank you! :-)

Comment: I highly recommend trying something and then showing what you've tried and explain why it fails for you.

Comment: for start try to get the current url first then use substr function

Comment: tried like this  <?php $title = isset($_GET['q'])?" ".ucfirst($_GET['q']):""; ?> but don't get anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest solution in those cases would be using (untested code, but should work):

```
<?php 
//get path
$urlPath = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
//get last element
$end = array_slice(explode('/', rtrim($urlPath, '/')), -1)[0];
//replace dashes with spaces and display 
echo ucwords(str_replace('-',' ',$end));
```

Comment: thanks but, when I call it with <?php echo $ucwords; ?> nothing show up :(

Comment: @Alexandru assuming you're going off of janmyszkier's code, are you storing anything in a `$ucwords` variable? That isn't defined in his solution.

Comment: should replace  $url with $urlPath and worked. Thanks!

Comment: ah, indeed, my bad. fixed that